# Read KML files in C++

Tags: c++, kml

I try to read/parse a KML file in C++. What is the best way/practice to read KML in C++. I've tried libkml, but I'm not able to build it correctly with Visual Studio 2013. Should I just read it as xml file?

Thanks.

Comment: You can always read is as xml if you don't mind some extra work. You even have an option of validating it against XSD schema to make sure you've got a valid KML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I use XMLReader class and it works. Depends on your size of your KML file, XMLReader may not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `[libkml][1]` to read `kml` and `kmz` files 
[libkml](https://github.com/google/libkml)